# Completion block called immediatly in UIView animation

Tags: ios, uiview, objective-c-blocks, uianimation

I am trying to change the colors of the subviews one by one but colors of all views are change immediately even though I have set the animation duration is 2seconds.

```
- (void)runAnimation
{
    NSMutableArray *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (UIView *bubble in self.subviews)
    {
        if(bubble.tag == 2500)
            [views addObject:bubble];
    }

    __weak PKCustomSlider *weak_self = self;
    __block NSInteger currentView = 0;
    self.animationBlock = ^{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
             NSLog(@"Animation block called again");
            [views[currentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            currentView += 1;
            if(!finished)
            {
                NSLog(@"Animation hasn't finished");
                return;
            }

            if (currentView == views.count){
                currentView = 0;
                NSLog(@"Animation block ended");
            }
            else
            {
                weak_self.animationBlock();
                NSLog(@"Animation block called again because views still available in the array");
            }
        }];

    self.animationBlock();
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Comment: I think the completion block is executed immediately if the view is not a subview of the current `UIWindow`.

Comment: @ianmacdonald absolutely right

Comment: But my self.subviews returns array of view. It is the subview of the window so only self.subviews returns array right?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to animate one view after another, you shouldn't have to rely on the completion block. The completion block can be called instantly if there is no animation to be done in the animation block.

You can do something like this:

```
- (void)runAnimation
{
    for (int i = 0; i < self.subviews.count; i++) {
        UIView *bubble = self.subviews[i];

        if (bubble.tag != 2500)
            continue;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:2*i options:0 animations:^{
            [bubble setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1]];
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing what the question wants, +1